# Строка добавляется в список с фигурными скобками, из-за этого не проходит проверка

Tags: python, ос

Формирую список из папок в исходной папке и сравниваю его с тем, который должен быть.
Проблема в том, что когда проверяю на компьютере, то всё работает нормально. Но эти папки я проверяю на сервере - и вот тут начинается проблема. Список формируется не просто из СЛОВ, а взятых в фигурные скобки {СЛОВ}, поэтому и проверка не проходит. Причем может одно, может два слова так делаться.

```
import os
from tkinter import Label, Tk, messagebox

name_of_directory_link = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Pap\\Object"
window = Tk()
shablon = []
for dirs in os.listdir(name_of_directory_link):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(name_of_directory_link, dirs)):
        shablon.append(str(dirs))
        messagebox.showinfo(None, dirs)
messagebox.showinfo(None, shablon)
if shablon == ['Исходные данные', 'РКД', 'Фото']:
    Label(window, text="Размещение верное", bg="green").pack()
else:
    Label(window, text="Размещение неверное!", bg="red").pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Add: Перенес принт, добавил изображение в консоли и изображение в messagebox.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Add2: Добавил вывод repr и результат проверки программы (папка содержит те же подпапки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Add3: оборачивание в фигурные скобки фраз с пробелом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите консольный вывод ваших print-ов.

Comment: @passant - Добавил фото консоли и если выводить через messagebox

Comment: Сделайте вывод `repr(shablon)` (или что вы через messagebox выводите). В принципе, добавьте в вопрос именно тот код, который у вас выводит эти сообщения.

Comment: @insolor - Добавил простое окно с messagebox

Comment: Тогда добавьте что выводит с `messagebox.showinfo(None, repr(shablon))`

Comment: @insolor - Просто проблема возникает тогда, когда я после формирования списка shablon сравниваю его с необходимым. Если я ищу в папке на компьютере, то программа корректно сравнивает и выводит "Размещение верное". Но когда на сервере проверяю точно такую же папку, то выводит "Размещение неверное"

Comment: Я понял. Нужно смотреть, что на сервере выводится в `repr(shablon)`, тогда будет понятно почему не совпдает.

Comment: @insolor Добавил

Comment: Ну вообще есть разница "Исходны данные" и "Исходные данные"

Comment: @insolor Почувствовал себя дураком... Весь день сидел с написанием этой программы, похоже уже глаз замылился. Сейчас попробую переименовать и проверить

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, заработало) только вот всё же интересно, почему в messagebox название выводится в фигурных скобках

Comment: @КостяКилиманов скорее всего messagebox (и скорее всего другие компоненты tkinter) так конвертируют списки в строку: элементы списка выводит через пробел, элементы с пробелами внутри оборачивает в фигурные скобки. Все кроме строк лучше явно в строку конвертировать, через тот же repr например.

Comment: @insolor Просто он только первый элемент перед в скобки, остальные нормально. Бывало, что и  2 элемента списка были в скобках.

Comment: Ну тут похоже что оборачивает из-за пробела в "Исходные данные". Может еще какие-то случаи есть, когда он решает обернуть.

Comment: @insolor Да, проверил) оборачивается только там, где есть пробелы)